# « Prendre le large »

Tags: expressions

J'ai écouté dans certaines chansons cette expression «Prendre le large».

Qu'est-ce que cela signifie?

Je n'ai pas entendu cette expression pendant mes conversations en français, seulement dans des chansons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short

Cela signifie **s'enfuir**.

---

#### Wiki first

D'après [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_le_large) :

> 1. (Marine) S’éloigner du rivage, gagner la haute mer.
> 2. (Figuré) (Familier) **S’enfuir**.
>
>    > *Malheureusement Raïssouli avait pris le large et, des montagnes où il s'était réfugié, il continua à terroriser Tanger, El-Kçar et Tetuan.*

---

#### Pour aller plus loin

D'après [expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/prendre-le-large-mettre-les-voiles.php) :

> S'éloigner, s'éclipser, **s'enfuir**.

Avec un superbe tableau récapitulatif des expressions des langues européennes avec le même sens.

---

Answer (score 2):

"*Le large*" c'est la haute mer. À l'origine, *prendre le large* veut dire partir dans un bateau en haute mer, donc loin du rivage.

Par extension, maintenant ça veut dire s'enfuir aussi loin qu'on peut, aussi vite qu'on peut. C'est une façon assez poétique de le dire.